# Contradicting solutions: Evaluate $a|(b+c)\implies a|b \space \lor a|c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, divisibility

I was requested to evaluate whether $a|(b+c)\implies a|b \space \lor a|c$ is a true proposition. So far I have been able to show the proposition is true *and* false, so either I've reached a mystical state or, which seems more likely, I'm going terribly wrong at some point.

*Showing it is true.* Assume $a|(b+c)$. Assume as well it is **not** the case that $a|b \space \lor a|c$. Then

- $b=aq_1+r_1, r_1> 0$
- $c=aq_2+r_2, r_2>0$

and

$$b+c = aq_1+r_1 + aq_2+r_2 =a(q_1+q_2)+(r_1+r_2) \tag{with $r_1+r_2>0$}$$

This implies $a \nmid(b+c)$, a contradiction to our hypothesis. Therefore $a|(b+c)\implies a|b \space \lor a|c$.

*Showing it is false*. Way simpler, probably the not wrong answer: $a=8, b=14, c=2$ is a counterexample: $8|(14+2)$ but $8\nmid 14$ and $8 \nmid 2$.

Clearly, something is wrong with the first proof. However, I am not able to see what it is. Could anybody point the error out?

Comment: You found a counterexample, hence the implication is false.

Comment: It is clearly wrong, but I can't see why the first proof is incorrect as well.

Comment: Perhaps the error is I am showing $\neg (a|b \lor a|c) \implies a \nmid (b+c)$ instead of what I wanted to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $b+c = aq_1+r_1 + aq_2+r_2 =a(q_1+q_2)+(r_1+r_2)$ with $r_1+r_2>0$.
>
> This implies $a \nmid(b+c)$

This is wrong. It is possible that $r_1+r_2$ itself is a multiple of $a$, so $b+c$ is a multiple of $a$.

In your example, with $a=8$, $b=14$ and $c=2$, we have $r_1=6$ and $r_2=2$, so $r_1+r_2=8$, which is a multiple of $8$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt!

Answer (score 2):

An important part of the division algorithm is that when $a = b q+r$, the residue $r$ must satisfy the inequality $0\le r \color{red}{< b}$.

If you want to use the division algorithm to conclude that a certain integer $a$ is not divisible by $b$ is not enough to write it as $a = bq+r$ with $r> 0$, you also need to check that $r<b$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. I'm marking Taladris' answer as correct simply because he answered first... Your answers are equally clarifying and I had to choose a rather arbitrary criteria. Sorry!